# How to Append the text at the top of the Jquery Grid

Tags: jquery

Here the syntax I am using for appending text.

```
   $("#table").append("<span>Append some text here..</span>");
```

I have a view like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<JQGridMVCExamples.Models.OrdersJqGridModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Trirand.Web.Mvc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="JQGridMVCExamples.Models" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Performance Linq</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/Scripts/jqgrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/Scripts/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/Content/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>           
        <%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrdersGrid, "JQGrid1") %>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("CodeTabs"); %>        
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Where do I need to keep this append in the view so that I can see the text top of the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to inject the `<span>` above your table, you should use jQuery's [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) rather than append, and you need to give the target `div` the id you are using in the prepend function.

So where you have

```
<div>           
        <%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrdersGrid, "JQGrid1") %>
</div>
```

(assuming this is your target div), make that

```
<div id="table">           
        <%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrdersGrid, "JQGrid1") %>
</div>
```

Comment: But its appending the string value at the bottom of the grid? not on the top of the grid?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the grid in your HTML? I was assuming it was the one I quoted above.